# Is every natural number a difference between natural numbers with greatest common divisor 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can one prove that $\{x : x=y-z, \gcd(y,z)=1, y,z\in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{N}$?

This problem has arisen at a problem in probability and I've never studied this kind of math before, so I apologize if it is tagged wrong.

Thanks

Comment: $x= (x+1)-1$. Or if you don't want to use $z=1$ take any number $m$ that is coprime to $x$ and use $x=(x+m)-m$.

Comment: Let $n$ be an integer bigger than $6$.  Then  $n$ is the sum of two relatively prime integers each bigger than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $x=(x+1)-1$. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Oh wow, that was trivial. Thanks!